# Como puedo agregar un callback a este metodo

Tags: angular

Como puedo agregar un callback a este subscribe? Al método que se lo quiero asignar es a `mostrarfavoritos`. El problema radica en que este `data.data.id` debe devolver `1 1 1 0 0`,  pero este siempre devuelve esos datos de manera desordenada, el idfinal es 2 siempre es el mismo y en data.data[index].id_ropa envia 21 luego 22 y asi hasta 25 compara que esos valores esten en la base de datos si esta devuelve 1 y si no esta devuelve 0, tengo en la base de datos de 21 al 23 lo que me debe devolver la secuencia de arriba, pero aveces la envia bien en otras desordenada

```
    let id=this.http2.getId()
            let idfinal=this.http2.getIdDesencryp(id)

            this.http.mostrarropa().subscribe(
              data => {
                 this.ropas=data.data
                 for (let index = 0; index < data.data.length; index++) {

                  this.http.mostrarfavoritos(idfinal,data.data[index].id_ropa).subscribe(
                    data => {
                       console.log(data.data.id)

                  }); 

                 }
            });
```

SERVICE

```
 mostrarfavoritos(iduser,idropa):Observable<any>{
    return this.http
    .post<Ropa>(
      this.apiUrl+"mostrarfavoritos",
      { iduser,idropa}
    )
    .pipe(map(data => data));
  }
```

API

en esta parte el recibe los datos que vienen del service en este caso este se ejecuta 5 veces ya que el for que esta en el component ts le manda 5 datos este se ejecuta 5 veces y cuando regresa los datos vinene en desorden. se supone que si el for ejecuta 1 por 1 debe recibir la respuesta que le corresponde. pero no es asi los datos llegan desordenados

```
private function mostrarfavoritos(){


        if ($this->get_request_method() != "POST") {

            $this->response('', 406, '');
        }


        $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');

        $json = json_decode($request_body);



        $iduser = $json->iduser;
        $idropa = $json->idropa;

        $sql = "call spMostrarFavorito('" . $iduser . "', '" . $idropa. "');";

        $resultados = mysqli_query($this->conexion, $sql);

        if (!$resultados) {


            $data = array(
                "success" => "false",
                "mensaje" => "Error Inesperado, vuelva a intentarlo.",
                "data" => $res,
            );
            $this->response($this->json($data), 200, 'json');
            $result->free();
            $this->db->close();

        } else {

            $data = array();
            $res = array();
            $d = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                $res = array(
                    "id" => $d["id"]
                );


                $data = array(
                    "success" => "true",
                    "data" => $res,
                );


            $this->response($this->json($data), 200, 'json');

            $resultado->free();
            $this->db->close();
        }

    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que contiene el subscribe  ya posee uno. Podrías darnos mas información sobre que es lo que necesitas hacer??

Comment: ya arriba especifique mejor. siempre me regresa los datos en desorden y no en secuencia

Comment: Ese orden que quieres no sólo puede depender de tu código, sino también del backend... Te sugiero que analices primero los datos desde postman o desde el mismo navegador a ver como lo devuelve

Comment: Hola Alberto. Supongo que `this.http` es un servicio. Puedes subirlo? Usando `rxjs` se pueden ordenar los datos antes del `subscribe` en caso de que no tengas accesso al backend.

Comment: ya coloque el panorama mas completo del problema

Comment: Me gustaría que colocaras los console logs.

Comment: Alberto, ya intentaste crear una variable de tipo array y hacerle un push  en cada iteración de for que vaya entrando.

Comment: si eso que esta hay lo meto en un array con push pero el problema radica en que el suscribe me los trae desordenados

Comment: Por que no utilizas un sort a ese array? ._.

Comment: @VíctorHugoTirado ese callback me devuelve todo desordenado los datos se envian uno por uno mas no todos juntos y a un asi cuando regresan los muestra desordenados

Comment: @AlexisNarvaez no puedo usarlo por que no siempre van a llegar en orden los 1 1 1 0 0 puede llegar otra secuencia. la idea es que asi como yo comparo asi me llegue el resultado. yo no puedo decir que la primera comparacion como  son iguales me devuelva 1 y ordenarlo con un sort y colocar 0 en la primera posicion no concuerda con la comparacion que se hizo

Comment: en pocas palabras no se trata de ordenar en la vista, si no de obtener los datos en el orden que son enviados desde el api

Comment: Cierto mala mía estoy buscando algún método, con rxjs se puede hacer pero casi no tengo conocimiento y estoy investigando.

Comment: @AlexisNarvaez pues estuve leyendo que angular no es secuencial que por lo tanto los muestra en desorden por que trabaja es en tiempo de ejecucion y logre buscar algo referente a callbacks en angular pero no se como usarlo